# How do I emit to an eventListener from inside a nested function in Node.js (javascript scoping issue)

Tags: events, node.js, scoping

I am writing code below that parses a sites API one at a time, than tells an event queue it is ready for the next object to parse.  I am having issues since I am still new to javascript scoping, and would like to emit from SiteParser or call the emitForNext function.  I cannot seem to bring emitForNext into scope in the error callback.

```
   function SiteParser(){
        this.emitForNext = function  (message) {
            this.emit("next", message);
        };

        this.pullJSON = function (path, processJSON) { //processJSON is a callback function    
            var options = {
                host: 'www.site.com',
                port: 80,
                path: path
            }

            //console.log("... processing "+path); 

            //pulls the entire json request via chunks
            http.get(options, function  (res) {
                var resJSON = ''; //stores the comment JSON stream given in the res
                res.on('data',  function (chunk) {
                    resJSON+=chunk;   
                });  
                res.on('end', function () {
                    var obJSON = (JSON.parse(resJSON));  

                    if (obJSON.hasOwnProperty("error")){ 
                        console.log(obJSON);
                        console.log('... ', path, ' does not exist');
                        //
                        //NEED A NEXT EVENT EMMITER HERE NEED TO FIGURE OUT SCOPE
                        //
                        //   
                    } else {
                        processJSON(obJSON); //call the callback function
                    }
                }) ;
            }).on('error', function  (e) {
                emitForNext("got error: " + e.message);
            });
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has function scoping, if you declare a variable with the var keyword, it will be local to the current function. When you access a variable, it will look to the scope chain which consist of the current function, it's parent function, …. Try:

```
function one() {
    var foo = 'foo';

    function two() {
        console.log(foo) // undefined. I'll explain this
        var foo = 'bar';
        console.log(foo) // bar
    }

    two()
    console.log(foo) // foo
}
one()
```

Most of the time we define variables at the beginning of functions, because a variable defined in function's body get hoisted. Basically, it means that it's available in the whole function, even before it's defined but in this case it's value is `undefined`.

For example if a variable is not defined we normally get a `ReferenceError`, but in the snippet below, both `console.log()` just print `undefined`.

```
function foo() {
     console.log(bar);
     if (0) {
         var bar = 'bar';
     }
     console.log(bar);
}
```

So, a common practice is that, when you write long functions, you map this to self.

```
function SiteParser() {
    var self = this;
    // ...
    .error('error', function(err) {
        self.emitForNext("got " + err.message);
    })
}
```

You should not write all your methods in the constructor, it's only usefull sometimes when we want privacy, but in this case you'd better use prototypes.

Putting this together, I would write:

```
var SiteParser = function() {};

SiteParser.prototype.emitForNext = function(message) {
    this.emit("next", message);
};

SiteParser.prototype.pullJSON = function(path, processJSON) { 
    var self    = this,
        options = {
            host: 'www.site.com',
            port: 80,
            path: path
        };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
        // ...
    }).on('error', function  (e) {
        self.emitForNext("got error: " + e.message);
    });
};
```

Comment: I chose to do it this way and it ended up working great, sorry it took a little while to implement your solution, I was busy implementing new features!

Answer (score 2):

To be able to access emitForNext, you need to call `self.emitForNext`, where `self` points to your instance of SiteParser.

Like so:

```
function SiteParser(){

    this.emitForNext = function  (message) {

        this.emit("next", message);

    };



    this.pullJSON = function (path, processJSON) { //processJSON is a callback function    

        var options = {

            host: 'www.site.com',

            port: 80,

            path: path

        };



        var self = this;



        //console.log("... processing "+path); 



        //pulls the entire json request via chunks

        http.get(options, function  (res) {

            var resJSON = ''; //stores the comment JSON stream given in the res

            res.on('data',  function (chunk) {

                resJSON+=chunk;   

            });  

            res.on('end', function () {

                var obJSON = (JSON.parse(resJSON));  



                if (obJSON.hasOwnProperty("error")){ 

                    console.log(obJSON);

                    console.log('... ', path, ' does not exist');





                    self.emitForNext(path + ' does not exist');

                } else {

                    self.emitForNext('Successfully parsed the response');

                    processJSON(obJSON); //call the callback function

                }

            }) ;

        }).on('error', function  (e) {

            self.emitForNext("got error: " + e.message);

        });

    };

}
```

However, it looks like you'd rather manage what you'll do next (like parsing the next object) in you callback, ie. in the body of `processJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store link to 'this'' object in SiteParser local scope.

```js
 function SiteParser () {
    var that = this; // store link to 'this' in local scope

    this.emitForNext = function (message) {
        this.emit("next", message);
    };

    this.pullJSON = function (path, processJSON) { //processJSON is a callback function    
        var options = {
            host: 'www.site.com',
            port: 80,
            path: path
        }

        //console.log("... processing "+path); 

        //pulls the entire json request via chunks
        http.get(options, function  (res) {
            var resJSON = ''; //stores the comment JSON stream given in the res
            res.on('data',  function (chunk) {
                resJSON+=chunk;   
            });  
            res.on('end', function () {
                var obJSON = (JSON.parse(resJSON));  

                if (obJSON.hasOwnProperty("error")){ 
                    console.log(obJSON);
                    console.log('... ', path, ' does not exist');
                    that.emitForNext();
                } else {
                    processJSON(obJSON); //call the callback function
                }
            }) ;
        }).on('error', function (e) {
            that.emitForNext("got error: " + e.message);
        });
    };
}
```